# scrpiting - mostrar el tipo de dato de cada columna

Tags: linux, bash, awk, scripting

Estoy tratando de obtener información sobre las columnas del dataset de kaggle, titanic.csv.

Las columnas son las siguientes:

```
"name","gender","age","class","embarked","country","ticketno","fare","sibsp","parch","survived"
```

Los valores de los datos esperados serían:

```
 $ name    : chr  
 $ gender  : chr  
 $ age     : num  
 $ class   : chr  
 $ embarked: chr  
 $ country : chr  
 $ ticketno: int  
 $ fare    : num  
 $ sibsp   : int  
 $ parch   : int  
 $ survived: chr
```

Cómo se podrían obtener los valores mediante scripting en Linux?

En `bash`, podría obtenerlo mediante `type`?
Veo que con `awk` se puede hacer también mediante `typeof()`.
En ambos casos desconozco cómo obtener el tipo de todas las columnas.

Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple vista, se me ocurren varias ideas:

1. Utilizar awk
2. Utilizar una regex

### 1. Awk

Puedes usar:

```
$ awk -F, 'NR==1;NR==2{print typeof($1)","typeof($2)","typeof($3)}' archivo
```

Donde $1, $2 y $3, son las tres columnas, y `NR==2` es el segundo record del csv. Todo lo puedes modificar a tu gusto.

### 2. Regex

La otra es usando `sed`.

Aquí se me ocurre una manera muy rebuscada, que al escribirla es facil pero al leerla no:

```
sed -rn '1p;2s/([^,][[:alpha:]]+[^,])+/(char)/g;2s/([^,][[:digit:]]+[^,])+/(num)/gp'
```

Que poniéndolo en práctica queda algo así:

```
$ sed -rn '1p;2s/([^,][[:alpha:]]+[^,])+/(char)/g;2s/([^,][[:digit:]]+[^,])+/(num)/gp' << __eof
campo1,campo2,campo3,campo4
cad1,123,cad2,321
__eof
campo1,campo2,campo3,campo4
(char),(num),(char),(num)
```