# Mostrar el tipo de datos de columnas de un csv

Tags: linux, bash

Estoy terminando de realizar un ejercicio, y necesito saber de que tipo es cada columna de un CSV (Entero, decimal, fecha ... ) a través de bash.

Esta es la parte que muestra el tipo de datos, pero no funciona correctamente. Ademas solo muestra si es `char` o `number`. **¿Habría alguna otra forma de simplificarlo?**

```
 cat dataset_cars.csv | sed -rn '1p;2s/([^,][[:alpha:]]+[^,])+/(char)/g;2s/([^,][[:digit:]]+[^,])+/(num)/gp'
```

Cuando lo ejecuto me devuelve lo siguiente, se ve que no lo hace realmente bien (Añade ceros, y paréntesis donde no debe):

```
,price,brand,model,year,title_status,mileage,color,vin,lot,state,country,condition
0,(num),(char),(char),(num),(char),(num)0,(char), (char(num),(num),(char),(char),(num)char)
```

Y la salida que espero debería de ser algo así:

Datos de prueba:

```
Columna1, Columna2, Columna3
prueba, 123, 123.89
```

Salida:

```
Columna1, Columna2, Columna3
texto, numerico, decimal
```

Comment: He añadido como salida: Texto, numerico ... y en el código que tengo la salida es: (char) y (num). Se puede mostrar la salida con el nombre que se prefiera, pero que indique que tipo de dato es cada columna

Comment: De entrada, esa función que pegaste es exactamente a una que hice yo en otro post, y por eso sé que tu entrada de datos esta mal, además que le exiges demasiado a esa regex. En mi respuesta me parece que hay otra que usa `awk`. Esa te puede ayudar.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [scrpiting - mostrar el tipo de dato de cada columna](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/500416/scrpiting-mostrar-el-tipo-de-dato-de-cada-columna)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pesar de lo que te puse en los comentarios, podrías utilizar este regex para `sed`:

```
1p;2s/([0-9]*[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]*)+/(string)/g;2s/([[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+)/(decimal)/g;2s/([[:digit:]]+)/(int)/g;2s/[[:blank:]]//gp
```

Vamos a separarla un poco para que no se vea tan pegada y críptica:

```
$ sed -rn '1p
2s/([0-9]*[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]*)+/(string)/g
2s/([[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+)/(decimal)/g
2s/([[:digit:]]+)/(int)/g
2s/[[:blank:]]//gp' archivo.txt
```

Donde supongo que el archivo `archivo.txt` tiene este tipo de contenido:

```
Columna1, Columna2, Columna3, col4, col5, col6,col7
row1, 123, 123.89,r,2.3, 0, n1um
row2, 456, 321.89,s,0.1, 1, n2um
```

Y la salida da algo como:

```
Columna1,Columna2,Columna3,col4,col5,col6,col7
(string),(int),(decimal),(string),(decimal),(int),(string)
```

En resumen, lo primero que hacemos con el comando es imprimir el primer renglón. Luego voy buscando patrones en el segundo renglón (que según a mi entender y sin comprobar) dónde se muestre que cada valor sea de una cadena, decimal, o entero.

Al final, tan sólo remuevo espacios en blanco de nuestro resultado que no son necesarios para checar el tipo; sólo para la presentación del resultado.

Claramente esta es una forma débil de aproximarse, ya que no tomamos en cuenta los separadores o los caracteres que definen un texto, como las comillas simples o dobles. Pero mientras sirva, puedes tomarla.

Quizás te podría ser de más ayuda mi respuesta con `awk`: [scrpiting - mostrar el tipo de dato de cada columna](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/500416/scrpiting-mostrar-el-tipo-de-dato-de-cada-columna)