# Recorrer columnas de un csv por bash

Tags: linux, bash, script, shell

Necesito recorrer y mostrar las columnas de un `.csv` por **bash**. Y además decir que tipo de dato es esa columna.

Ahora mismo tengo este código:

```
 sed -rn '1,2s/[[:blank:]]//g;1p;2s/([0-9]*[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]*)+/(string)/g;2s/([[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+)/\(decimal\)/g;2s/([[:digit:]]+)/(int)/g;2p' student-mat.csv
```

Y este me devuelve esta salida:

```
school,sex,age,address,famsize,Pstatus,Medu,Fedu,Mjob,Fjob,reason,guardian,traveltime,studytime,failures,schoolsup,famsup,paid,activities,nursery,higher,internet,romantic,famrel,freetime,goout,Dalc,Walc,health,absences,G1,G2,G3
(string),(string),(int),(string),(string),(string),(int),(int),(string)_(string),(string),(string),(string),(int),(int),(int),(string),(string),(string),(string),(string),(string),(string),(string),(int),(int),(int),(int),(int),(int),(int),(int),(int),(int)
```

Es decir, me muestra primero todas las columnas y a continuación muestra el tipo de dato que es. Pero no es la salida que busco, necesito que me lo muestre de esta forma:

```
school -> (string)
sex -> (string)
age -> (int)
...
```

**¿Como puedo modificar el código para que me lo muestre de esta forma?** El código completo es el siguiente:

```
while getopts ":v" option; do
 case $option in
 v) varg=${OPTARG}
 echo "\nFORMATO DEL FICHERO"
 file student-mat.csv
 echo "\nTIPOS DE DATOS DE LAS COLUMNAS"
 sed -rn '1,2s/[[:blank:]]//g;1p;2s/([0-9]*[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]*)+/(string)/g;2s/([[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+)/\(decimal\)/g;2s/([[:digit:]]+)/(int)/g;2p' student-mat.csv
 exit
;;
esac
done
```

Cuando se llama al script con la opción `-v` se muestra la salida que esta mas arriba.

Comment: Sólo por curiosidad, Es para una tarea entre varios? Esa primera parte de la pregunta la contesté para varios que la preguntaban en SO

Comment: ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo de fichero inicial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al resultado le puedes poner un script de `awk`:

```
awk '
NR==1{split($0,columnas,",")} 
NR==2{split($0,tipo_de_dato,",")} 
END{ for (i=1; i <= length(columnas); i++) 
    printf "%s -> %s\n", columnas[i], tipo_de_dato[i] }'
```

Por ejemplo, suponiendo que el archivo `archivo.txt` es de la forma:

```
Columna1,Columna2,Columna3,col4,col5
row1, 123, 123.89,r,2.3
row2, 456, 321.89,s,0.1
```

Podemos usar:

```
$ sed -rn '1p
2s/([0-9]*[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]*)+/(string)/g
2s/([[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+)/(decimal)/g
2s/([[:digit:]]+)/(int)/g
2s/[[:blank:]]//gp' archivo.txt \
| awk '
NR==1{split($0,columnas,",")} 
NR==2{split($0,tipo_de_dato,",")} 
END{ for (i=1; i <= length(columnas); i++) 
    printf "%s -> %s\n", columnas[i], tipo_de_dato[i] }'
```

Y tenemos:

```
Columna1 -> (string)
Columna2 -> (int)
Columna3 -> (decimal)
col4 -> (string)
col5 -> (decimal)
```

Y, como dije en estas preguntas:

- [Mostrar el tipo de datos de columnas de un csv](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/502309/mostrar-el-tipo-de-datos-de-columnas-de-un-csv)
- [scrpiting - mostrar el tipo de dato de cada columna](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/500416/scrpiting-mostrar-el-tipo-de-dato-de-cada-columna)

Te sugiero no usar `sed`, y mejor usar `awk`. Así ya tienes un script que, tanto te checa el dato, como te formatea la salida bien flipante.